# WebAPI and Async issues for SMS provider

Tags: c#, api, asynchronous

I'm trying to call an API provided by an SMS service VoodooSMS. They do not have any documentation on how to implement in c#. i have attempted the following however it never breaks on the response.StatusCode. Using fiddler i can see the a request is sent but with 0 bytes as content and no response from server. I have included the live API key so please be mindful, this will be changed soon but there are 20 credits there to test.

This is the documentation from Voodoo SMS https://www.voodoosms.com/api/#introduction

```
        async Task<string> sendVoodooSMS(ClientSMS clientSMS)
    {

        var request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.voodoosms.com/balance") as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer BPNLmUBX9mjvYjN1kSgVW8wCocCnabPcrdoSzpryRRiq2w"); 

        var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
        }

        return response.StatusCode.ToString();
    }




    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize(Roles = "clients")]
    public ActionResult sendSMS(ClientSMS clientSMS)
    {

        ///
        ///
        /// TEST VOODOO SMS
        ///
        ///
        var voodooMessageResponse = this.sendVoodooSMS(clientSMS);

    }
```

Have never written a service to consume a RESTful API before in C#, only in AJAX so i'm a bit stuck. Any help greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Sorry just to clarify, a break point on this line             if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) is never hit, the code jumps back to the calling method. The calling method is within my controller that i want to await on the result so i can update the method return type to the following.

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize(Roles = "clients")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> sendSMS(ClientSMS clientSMS)
    {

        ///
        ///
        /// TEST VOODOO SMS
        ///
        ///
        var voodooMessageResponse = await this.sendVoodooSMS(clientSMS);
```

Fiddler shows this which makes no sense to me at all.

[Fiddler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo0Dz.png)

Comment: It is not very clear on which line it doesn't break.

Comment: Your code is not async but that is Ok. There should be some response, tell us the status code.

Comment: "no response from server" - did you test this request (and bearer token) with Postman?

Comment: The API is using SSL.  So there is probably an issue at the TCP level.  HTTP uses TCP as the transport layer.  Check if any TCP is being sent and look for a [FIN] indicating the connection closing. Also check you IE Browser setting to see if SSL is enabled.  Tools : Internet Options : Advanced.

Comment: Executed the code provided on my end. It says "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found." at request.GetResponse() itself. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal i get 401 when i try to use .net fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/2Eembz

Comment: @PaulRead: Yeah, well, anyways,.... do you have a valid test bearer token? The one you mentioned expired it seems... I'm unable to generate a test one myself as it works only in UK/Ireland.

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal yes, sorry the previous api key might be geoIP restricted. this new one isn't TM6mROT5hcQ1jKazDhAHTFDbdRRtdz6yB3ZTHuPpNfgxr8